# How to display two jquery pages side by side for tablet view using mediaquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, media-queries

I have a mobile website build with jquery having following structure

1. login page (data-role="page" id="login" ..)
2. list of activity (data-role="page" id="approvallist" ..)
3. activity details (data-role="page" id="purchaseorderdetails" ..)
4. extrainfo (data-role="page" id="reassign" ...)

I have build this app for mobile where navigation are as below Page 1 --> Page 2 --> Page 3 --> Page 4

I have used jquery tag $.mobile.changePage("#reassign") for those navigations.

Now my problem is :

**How can i align two pages (page 2 and page 3) and (page 2 and page 4) side by side for tablet view using mediaquery.
For tablet after login, page 2 and page 3 will be displayed side by side, but for mobile phone only page 2 will be displayed.**

When i have followed this example page 2 and page 3 are not aligning side by side and again during the display of page 1 (i.e login page), page 2 and 3 are displaying and overlaying each other.

Could you please guide me to solve this puzzle.

Thanks Ajoy Sinha

Somebody provide some clue please ..Thanks Ajoy

Comment: Somebody provide some clue please ..Thanks Ajoy

Comment: In JQM, you can show one page, you can't show multiple pages at the same time.